ASPNET Indentity, Role Entity is null

With the following code, when I call the endpoint, the User.UserRole is populated, but the actual Role is always null and I need the role name. What am I missing to populate the role name itself?
I am trying to get the roles that the user is assigned to in an array for the entire list of users.

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetAll()
        {
            var result = await _context.Person.Include(e => e.User).Include(e => e.User.UserRoles).ToListAsync();
            return result;
           
        }

 // User Class
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IEntityBase
    {
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim<string>> Claims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin<string>> Logins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserToken<string>> Tokens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }**
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }


           // This is my app db context
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
            {
                // Each User can have many UserClaims
                b.HasMany(e => e.Claims)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserLogins
                b.HasMany(e => e.Logins)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many UserTokens
                b.HasMany(e => e.Tokens)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey(ut => ut.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();

                // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
                b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                    .WithOne(e => e.User)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
            {
                // Each Role can have many entries in the UserRole join table
                b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                    .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                    .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                    .IsRequired();
            });

  

